# Pandas - Style - Background Gradient using other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-styles

I like using the background_gradient as it helps me look at my dataframes in an excel way.
But I'm wondering if I there is a way I could map the colors to the figures in another dataframe.
For example, something I am keen to do is to color the dataframe using a dataframe of zscores so i can see quickly the value of outliers.

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) 
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
A.style.background_gradient(???)
```

I'm wondering how to use `background_gradient` so that it uses the values in the dataframe B to style A.

Comment: How to mean style A from values dataframe B. Like colouring the cell based on  row index and column index from one Dataframe in another?

Comment: Yes I would use the colors created by the background_gradient applied to B, and use those colors on A.

Comment: Is my answer what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see a different method other than altering the [background_gradient code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d81f3df81eb0a4d077ae1317df74d509cdc446/pandas/formats/style.py#L817) for transferring style from one dataframe to other i.e

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib import colors

def b_g(s, cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0):
    # Pass the columns from Dataframe A 
    a = A.loc[:,s.name].copy()
    rng = a.max() - a.min()
    norm = colors.Normalize(a.min() - (rng * low),
                        a.max() + (rng * high))
    normed = norm(a.values)
    c = [colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]
    return ['background-color: %s' % color for color in c]

B.style.apply(b_g,cmap='PuBu')
```

Output :

[image: Dataframes]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Barath. I imagined it was going to be the way to do it. Thanks for showing the code to get that.
Regards

Comment: Anyway to save styler objects to a png/pdf?

Comment: @thomas.mac I dont think we can save styler objects to a png. The answer is like applying the style on a different dataframe and return the style so the same is applied in the new dataframe. The solution only works if the shape of both is equal.

Comment: hi @Bharath, how do i modify your code to the effect of "axis=None", as above code shade column-wise. Thanks!